# What is a good book on Cryptography with an emphasis on algebraic aspects?

Tags: reference-request, cryptography

I have heard of the subject "Cryptography"  but never looked much into it. But this summer, I thought is the best time to look into the subject and see if it will interest me.

In U.G, I did Cryptography chapter in Burton's book on Number theory and I was pretty much attracted to Cryptography.

Now having studied all the main parts of algebra, I was hoping to find the best book to look into the subject which an algebra guy would like. Please can anyone suggest me some book to do in this summer.

Comment: Just to be sure: you realize that coding theory and cryptography are different subjects?

Comment: nop actually I have no idea

Comment: Okay. Good I asked. Cryptography is about protecting information from access by non-authorized entities (so about making something a "secret"). However, coding theory is about protecting information against degradation by natural/random errors, and generally storing information in efficient ways (so about storing it in a "good" way). Both are interesting, and have something to do with algebra,  but they are not  very related. There is some overlap, but they are quite different.

Comment: so should I edit it as algebraic cryptography, or there is no such thing like that?

Comment: I am interested in Cryptography , about protecting information from access by non-authorized entities (, in ways that it is studied with algebra,), so please feel free to edit the question in necessary ways

Comment: I edited it slightly.

Comment: [Introduction to Modern Cryptography by Katz & Lindell](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1466570261/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_3/275-8276457-0875934?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_r=1R1W8D0DCDTZQ074C38F&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_p=569136327&pf_rd_i=1441926747) is nice if you're taking a course, but it lacks answers to the exercises. It's very thorough, very rigorous, and has a lot of material.

Answer (score 1):

Koblitz, *Algebraic Aspects of Cryptography*, by the co-inventor of Elliptic Curve Cryptography is a good choice.